# Adding Missing Rows and Interpolating their Values

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I'm working with the following Dataframe,

```
altitude    density east_wind   north_wind
0   5   0.020567    39.714397   6.795392
1   7   0.016871    41.171996   6.852655
2   9   0.013839    42.629594   6.909918
3   11  0.011351    44.087193   6.967182
4   13  0.009311    45.544791   7.024445
```

and I'm looking to have a continuous values rather than just odd numbers in `altitude` and then fill in the missing values using SciPy's `.interpolate(method='linear')` and extend the interpolation to an `altitude` value of `20`

**Expected Output**

```
altitude    density east_wind   north_wind
0   5   0.020567    39.714397   6.795392
1   6   0.018871    41.171996   6.852655
2   7   0.015839    42.629594   6.909918
3   8   0.013351    44.087193   6.967182
4   9   0.010311    45.544791   7.024445
...
...
9   19  0.000351    50.087193   11.967182
10  20  0.000311    51.544791   12.024445
```

Please Advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpolation in Pandas is relatively easy, extrapolation is a bit harder. So we "cheat" and manually calculate altitude=21 row, then call `reindex` and `interpolate`

first we load the data

```
from io import StringIO
data = StringIO(
"""
altitude    density east_wind   north_wind
0   5   0.020567    39.714397   6.795392
1   7   0.016871    41.171996   6.852655
2   9   0.013839    42.629594   6.909918
3   11  0.011351    44.087193   6.967182
4   13  0.009311    45.544791   7.024445
""")
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='\s+', index_col=0)
df
```

Then

```
last_index = 21
df2 = df.set_index('altitude')
df2.loc[last_index] = df2.loc[df2.index[-1]] + (last_index - df2.index[-1])*(df2.loc[df2.index[-1]] - df2.loc[df2.index[-2]])/(df2.index[-1] - df2.index[-2])
df2.reindex(range(5,22)).interpolate().reset_index()
```

to get

```
      altitude    density    east_wind    north_wind
--  ----------  ---------  -----------  ------------
 0           5   0.020567      39.7144       6.79539
 1           6   0.018719      40.4432       6.82402
 2           7   0.016871      41.172        6.85266
 3           8   0.015355      41.9008       6.88129
 4           9   0.013839      42.6296       6.90992
 5          10   0.012595      43.3584       6.93855
 6          11   0.011351      44.0872       6.96718
 7          12   0.010331      44.816        6.99581
 8          13   0.009311      45.5448       7.02445
 9          14   0.008291      46.2736       7.05308
10          15   0.007271      47.0024       7.08171
11          16   0.006251      47.7312       7.11034
12          17   0.005231      48.46         7.13897
13          18   0.004211      49.1888       7.1676
14          19   0.003191      49.9176       7.19623
15          20   0.002171      50.6464       7.22487
16          21   0.001151      51.3752       7.2535
```

Comment: I've tried implementing your code and it yields an error `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Comment: hmm. I edited my answer showing how I load the data -- does it work if you follow my steps exactly, including data loading? and what is the dtype of 'altitude' in your original df?

Comment: I've tried your code, the interpolation part works just fine but the extrapolation results in some unreasonable values which do not align with the trends. Are there any other ways of carrying out the extrapolation?

Comment: It does linear extrapolation as you originally specified. Does this answer your original question? 'what is the right extrapolation' is a separate, and rather broad, question

Comment: When I use your code for extrapolation, for `altitude` values of `20` and `21`, I get huge numbers like `-193.611983` and `257.198980`for `winds`, whereas in your results they are reasonable. Why is this happening?

Comment: It is rather hard to say without seeing the data -- is it different from what you provided in your question? ,The last two rows basically determine the extrapolation. Of course if you have a 'feel' for what the values should be for altitude `21`, from some other information on what's reasonable, you can just put it into `df2.loc[last_index] = ...` directly

Comment: Here's the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lAtI5OuCXrp8LXf45SzIR0QZ3vMSQyJC/view?usp=sharing) to the data and these are the column names `t_columns = ['altitude', 'density', 'east_wind', 'north_wind']
`

Comment: The `last_index` would end at `140` in my case

Comment: can you see the changes I made to that sheet? That shows linear extrapolation on a plot?  for the third column?

Comment: I'm unable to see the changes, I guess you'll have to send the document

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Tcc-awPEVzMe2Mol-0FQyQbBFWHpcbvi_QOlXv5sJc4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes I do see the plots, those are some usually high values for `winds` I guess

Comment: My point being you generally cannot just linearly extrapolate your data that far and expect a reasonable answer. while the code above does the thing you asked, it may not be what you really need